# In C#, is there a way to pass an array to a method that takes in a variable length parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have this method I want to call, and it's from a third-party library so I cannot change its signature:

`void PrintNames(params string[] names)`

I'm writing this method that needs to call `PrintNames`:

```
void MyPrintNames(string[] myNames) {
  // How do I call PrintNames with all the strings in myNames as the parameter?
}
```

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. You can call it with a `string` array of any length, or you can use the `params` keyword to allow calling the method with any number of arguments (provided they're the same type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try

```
PrintNames(myNames);
```

You would know if you had a look at the specs on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

They demonstrated it quite clearly - note the comment in the sample code:

```
// An array argument can be passed, as long as the array 
// type matches the parameter type of the method being called.
```

Comment: I see, initially I had `IList<string> myNames`

Comment: @shengmin `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which means that you could have used `myNames.ToArray()`, as in `PrintNames(myNames.ToArray());` :) Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  The compiler will convert multiple parameters into an array, or just let you pass in an array directly.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var b = new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
      Console.WriteLine(Foo(b)); // Call Foo with an array

      Console.WriteLine(Foo("Four", "Five")); // Call Foo with parameters
   }

   public static int Foo(params string[] test)
   {
      return test.Length;
   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://ideone.com/XONOEB)